# Torsocks connection refused error when using python package manager on Tails

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, tor, socks

I'm new in Tails Linux and I'm facing some problems installing apps through torsocks.

In this example I've installed python3-pip through `apt-get` and everything was ok, however when I run `python3 -m pip install "something"` I get an error like:

> PERROR Torsocks socks5 libc connection refused.

I already tried to run the command with torify, torsocks, change the tor port to 9051 and 9151, use --proxy with the command and nothing worked.

It includes commands as CURL and many others

How can we solve that?

Answer (score 0):

From the [tails](https://tails.boum.org/doc/first_steps/additional_software/index.en.html) docs:

> Packages that use the network need to be configured to go through Tor. They are otherwise blocked from accessing the network.

By default, the `pip` package manager won't make its requests through a socks proxy, so you will have to manually route its connection.

I'd recommending using [proxychains](https://github.com/haad/proxychains).  (a guide for installing this on tails can be found [here](https://forkdrop.io/installing-and-using-proxychains-utility-on-tails-live-boot))

Once you have it installed, simply run `proxychains pip install <package name>`